# Routing without the controller name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a few controllers ,
One let say computer controller 
It has action for laptop, desktop gadgets 
i would like to have pages name :www.MyDomain/laptop (and so on )
and one let say electronic controller 
it has action TV, DVD, (and so on )
i would like to have pages name :www.MyDomain/TV (and so on )
Without specifies  the controller?
**I don’t understand what happen to my question before I can't edit
(I hope the admin will delete it )**

Comment: Your previous question must have been asked under a different account.  If you provide a link, I can merge accounts.

Comment: @SLaks, I guess it's this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110380/routing-without-naming-controller/6110482

Comment: Your accounts have been merged.  You can now edit or delete your previous question.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this by specifying route constraints:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Computers",
    "{name}",
    new { controller = "Computers", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { page = "laptop|desktop" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Gadgets",
    "{name}",
    new { controller = "Electronic", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { page = "tv|dvd" }
);
```

Now `/laptop` and /desktop will be routed to the `Index` action of the `ComputersController` and `/tv` and `/dvd` will be routed to the `Index` action of the `GadgetsController`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ViewLaptop", // Route name
    "/laptop", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Computers", action = "Laptop" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

This should do it.

Comment: Hi, thanks, am I suppose to write rout like you have suggested for every single page?
routes.MapRoute(
    "ViewLaptop", // Route name
    "/laptop", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Computers", action = "Laptop" } // Parameter defaults
);
?

Comment: This way you may check @Darin 's answer, he had put it in a more variable way, so you have one action but with a `page` variable to determine the type you want to browse.